# Create a range of numbers with Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to create a simple range of numbers on Google Sheets in Android the same way you would do it on a computer: drag the corner spot down selecting 2 consecutive numbers.

So I would input "1", "2", and then extend to 80 by dragging down to have: "1", "2", "3", "4", ... But it does not work on Android.

Any way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you using the Drive and Sheets apps, or are you trying to do that in the browser?